# Google maps Javascript API very slow on IE 11

Tags: performance, javascript, internet-explorer-11, api

We have a professional app that uses the Google maps Javascript API with the correct key. The call is done through an HTML page that invokes js scripts. Because it is fairly involved, with the placement of markers notably, I have created a very simple html document to test things, and that has the same slowness problems on IE 11. My computer is Win7 SP1 and is all up to date (DirectX included). If I open the html doc in Chrome, response times are acceptable. With IE 11, after just a few clicks to zoom in, zoom out, pan, etc., it will get stuck and take quite a long time to respond. I have not found any useful information about things to do besides checking for updates (as I said, everything is up to date). Users have been reporting this to me since Jan 15, 2019, but I have not been able to verify the exact date of the problem by myself. The "simplified" html doc is this:

```
<title>Simple Map</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">

<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>

  #map {

    height: 100%;

  }

  html, body {

    height: 100%;

    margin: 0;

    padding: 0;

  }

</style>
```

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script>

  var map;

  function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8

    });

  }

</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

Many thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Same problem here. You could keep an eye on https://stackoverflow.com/q/54293430/3235496

Answer (score -1):

we've experienced similar problems in the last few days. To solve it we've forced Google Maps API version 3.34 instead of 3.35 (which should be the last one).

Comment: Thank you, I tried forcing the version (it was originally 3.19, identical problem as without any version, as with 3.35 or 3.34 specifically), but that didn't do it for me. I am also having the problem of my post marked off-topic and not knowing how to deal with that!

Comment: I have found a solution that works for me: setting the version to 3.34 AND setting visibility off to the POI feature, labels element. I will add this to the Stackoverflow thread kindly pointed to by @manlio. Thank you.